# help on antiderivative of a vector function

Tags: integration

Suppose I have $f(x) = {Sx\over ||x||}$, where $S$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix and $x$ is a vector of length $n$. I'd like to know the antiderivative of $f(x)$, which is a real-valued function $g(x)$ and its partial derivative w.r.t $x$ is $f(x)$. Thanks.

Comment: It is neither ||x|| and sqrt(x^T S x). The first gives partial derivative x/||x|| and the second gives Sx/sqrt(x^T S x).

Comment: I should add S is a positive definite symmetric matrix